# Woocommerce email table customization

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, html-email

I need woocommerce order completed send mail in a table format that has header,footer and message. The width of the table woocommerce uses is 600 in center box table.

So, I want to customize that table width size to change it to 100%. Does it have any hook or filter to customize that table width?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and most common approach to do is to create a folder in your theme called **woocommerce/** and then copy the entire **templates/** directory from your woocommerce plugin or [github](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce) into that. This will override the functionality from the plugin.

The file that you will want to edit is email-styles.php. You can delete all of the other files unless you are going to make changes to them in the templates directory of your theme.

[your_theme/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-styles.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-styles.php)

Answer (score 5):

As ham-sandwich indicates you should create the appropriate folders in your childtheme. But you have to omit the templates-folder. The appropriate folders are:

```
your_theme/woocommerce/emails/
```

The file you need to copy and edit is rather `email-header.php`. Here you can find the hardcoded table width. In my case on lines 33, 37 and 50.

Worked like a charm for me.